# JDBC requests to Oracle 11g failing to be commited although apparently succeding

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, commit

We have an older web-based application (Java with Spring 2.5.4 framework) running on a GlassFish 3.1 (build 43) server.  This application was recently (a few weeks ago) re-directed to use an Oracle 11g (11.2.0.3.0) database and ojdbc6.jar/orai18n.jar (up from Oracle 10g 10.2.0.3.0 and ojdbc14.jar) -- using a JDBC Thin connection.  The application is using org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource version 1.2.2 for connections and the database requests are handled either through Spring jdbcTemplate (via the JdbcDaoSupport abstract class) or Spring's PlatformTransactionManager.

This morning we noticed that application users were able to enter information, modify it and later to retrieve and print that data through the application, but that there were no committed updates for the last 24 hours.  This application currently has only a few users each day and they are apparently sharing the same connection which has been kept open by the connection pool during the last day and so their uncommitted updates were visible through the application, but not through other connections to the database.  When the connection was closed, the uncommitted updates were lost.

Examining the server logs showed no errors from the time of the last committed changes to the database through the times of printed reports the next morning.  In addition, even if some of the changes had been (somehow) made with the JDBC connection being set to Auto-Commit false, there were specific commits made for some of those updates that were part of a transaction which, as part of a try/catch block should have either executed one of the "transactionManager.commit(transactionStatus);" or "transactionManager.rollback(transactionStatus);" calls that must have been processed without error.  It *looks* as though the commit was returning successfully, but no commit actually occurred.

Restarting the GlassFish domain and the application restored the normal operation with the various updates being committed as they are entered.

My question is has anyone seen or heard about anything like this occurring and, if so, what could have caused it?

Thank you for any ideas here -- we are at a loss.

---

Some new information:

1. Examination of our Oracle 11g Server showed that near the time that we believe that the commits appeared to stop, there were four operations blocked on some other operation that we were not able to fully resolve, but was probably an update.
2. Examination of the Glassfish Server logs showed that the appearance of the worker threads changed following this estimated start time and fewer threads were appearing in the log until only one thread continued to be used for several hours.
3. The problem occurred again about one week later and was caught after about 1/2 hour.  At this time, there were two worker threads in operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred due to a combination of two things. The first was a method that setup a Spring Transaction, but had an exit that bypassed both the TransactionManager.commit() and the TransactionManager.rollback() (as well as the several SQL requests making up the transaction). Although this was admittedly incorrect coding, in the past, this transaction was closed and therefore had no effect on subsequent usage.

The solution was to insure that the transaction was not started if there was nothing to be done; or, in general double check to make sure that all transactions, once started, are completed.

I am not certain of the exact how or why this problem began presenting itself, so the following is partly conjectured. Apparently, upgrading to Oracle 11g and/or switching to the ojdbc6.jar driver altered the earlier behavior of the incorrect code so that the transaction was not terminated and the connection auto-commit was left false.  (It could also be due to some other change that we have not identified since the special case above happens rarely – but does happen.) The corresponding JDBC connection appears to be bound to a specific GlassFish worker thread (I will call this a 'bad' thread in the following as opposed to the normally acting 'good' threads). Whenever this 'bad' thread is used to handle an application request (for this particular application), changes are uncommitted and selects return dirty data. As time goes on, when a change is requested on a 'good' thread and JDBC connection that already has an uncommitted change made on the 'bad' thread, than the new request hangs and the worker thread also hangs. Eventually all but the 'bad' worker thread are hung and everything seems to work correctly from the application viewpoint, but nothing is ever committed.

Again, the solution was to correct the bad code.